# Can't assign file name to environment variable inside vim

Tags: c, gcc, vim, environment-variables

Finally I want to compile my source code with gcc using vimux

(suppose filename is test.c)

*Before vimux I did*

```
:!gcc % -o test
```

*After install vimux I do*

```
nmap <leader>z :let $file_name = expand('%:t:r')<cr>:let $full_file_name = %<cr>:call VimuxRunCommand("gcc $full_file_name -o $file_name")<cr>
```

*But I've error*

> Invalid expression: %

I also tried did this by using vim variable because I thought problem was with scope

Comment: Use `:!make %:r` instead; you can get more options to your compiler more easily if you use a makefile.  As it stands, you're not using `-Wall` and hence are wasting `gcc`.  You can't afford not to compile with `-Wall`; if I had my way, you'd be compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes` (and that's easily done with a makefile, and harder with what you're proposing to use).

Comment: `:make %<` is even better

Comment: Otherwise, I don't see the point of using an environment variable to execute this Vim command. Fill directly the final string to the command. BTW, with mono-file projects, just `make` is enough, we don't even need a `Makefile`. In the end, it could become something like: `:call VimuxRunCommand('make '.expand('%<'))` -- but you'll loose the quickfix feature which doesn't require tmux anymore to compile in background, but vim plugins.

Answer (score 0):

As @JonathanLeffler said, `make` is better, but if you really want to go on with gcc, you should:

- Expand also `$full_file_name` , not just `file_name`
- Use `shellescape`, you don't want spaces in file names to be a problem

Your code should become something like:

`nmap <leader>z :let $file_name = shellescape(expand('%:t:r'))<cr>:let $full_file_name = shellescape(expand('%:p'))<cr>:call VimuxRunCommand("gcc " . $full_file_name . " -o " . $file_name)<cr>`

The `%:p` is because I guess you want the file name with the full path.

Comment: it does'n work. Output: `gcc $full_file_name -o $file_name` `clang: error: no input files`

Comment: @helsereet I missed the concatenation, I cannot test it but it should work now (I've edited the answer)